# How to use free sound for commercial use?

Tags: copyright, software, music

I discovered that some sound effects in Minecraft comes from web sites that offers free sfx, some of these sounds are under the 'CC BY-NC 3.0' licence which is a non-commercial one.

Yet, Minecraft use these sounds commercially as the game is not free.

How is it possible?

Comment: Just because some of the sound effects are similar does not mean Minecraft got them from those Web sites.

Comment: Do you mean that maybe that same sound is in another web site that distribute the sound under other conditions ? (Like, you have to pay the sound but you can use it commercially)

Comment: It depends on the sound. For example if I record a sound of me breaking a bottle, that is my own sound. Then, if someone else records a sound of him breaking his own bottle, then that is his own sound. But if you listen to both sounds, maybe they sound very close or identical.

Comment: I see what you mean, but in Minecraft's case, some sounds are the exact same ones from those on some web sites. They don't just sound identical, it just IS the same sound

Comment: It's possible that the sounds on the web sites were ripped/recorded from Minecraft.  I have seen many sites do this in the past with sound samples from other sources. They could simply have taken those recordings from the game and then slapped a CC-BY-NC license on them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### There are several possibilities

1. The effects are not the same
2. Minecraft has them under a different licence from the owner
3. Minecraft is committing copyright violation
4. And the most likely: they belong to Minecraft and someone has illegally uploaded them to the site

Comment: The illegal upload is quite possible in case 1 to 3 as well.